# Stricter typing of possible call signatures defined in interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to define whether a function should contain an argument via an interface. The library I'm developing calls for many different methods to be generated, and hardcoding those methods would require too much maintenance; so I figured that types would be a good place to define such things.

Perhaps this is best explained with code. Here's a library that abstracts some rest API:

```js
interface RequestInterface {
  endpoint: string
  body?: unknown
}

interface GetPosts extends RequestInterface {
  endpoint: '/posts'
  body: never
}

interface CreatePost extends RequestInterface {
  endpoint: '/posts'
  body: string
}

function Factory<R extends RequestInterface> (endpoint: R['endpoint']) {

  return (body?: R['body']): void => {

    console.log(`Hitting ${endpoint} with ${body}`)

  }
}

const myLibrary = {

  getPosts: Factory<GetPosts>('/posts'),
  createPosts: Factory<CreatePost>('/posts'),

}

myLibrary.getPosts('something') // => Correctly errors
myLibrary.createPosts(999)      // => Correctly errors
myLibrary.createPosts()         // => I want this to error
```

In the above, I'm defining the `endpoint` and `body` of a particular type of request in my interfaces. Although the TypeScript compiler correctly guards me against passing the *wrong* argument types, it doesn't guard me against not passing a value when one is required.

I understand why TypeScript doesn't error (because the method defined in factory ***can*** be undefined according to my typings), but I figured the above code was a good way of describing what I want to achieve: a quick, declarative library of methods which satisfy a particular type.

#### A Possible Solution

If I'm willing to extend my interfaces from two separate interfaces (one or the other) then I can achieve something close to what I want using [Construct Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```js
interface RequestInterface {
  endpoint: string
  call: () => void
}

interface RequestInterfaceWithBody {
  endpoint: string
  call: {
    (body: any): void
  }
}

interface GetPosts extends RequestInterface {
  endpoint: '/posts'
}

interface CreatePost extends RequestInterfaceWithBody {
  endpoint: '/posts'
  call: {
    (body: string): void
  }
}

function Factory<R extends RequestInterface|RequestInterfaceWithBody> (endpoint: R['endpoint']): R['call'] {

  return (body): void => {

    console.log(`Hitting ${endpoint} with ${body}`)

  }
}

const myLibrary = {

  getPosts: Factory<GetPosts>('/posts'),
  createPosts: Factory<CreatePost>('/posts'),

}

myLibrary.getPosts()            // => Correctly passes
myLibrary.getPosts('something') // => Correctly errors
myLibrary.createPosts(999)      // => Correctly errors
myLibrary.createPosts()         // => Correctly errors
myLibrary.createPosts('hi')     // => Correctly passes
```

Aside from the fact that I need to pick between two "super" types before extending anything, a major problem with this is that the Construct Signature argument is not very accessible.

Although not demonstrated in the example, the types I create are also used elsewhere in my codebase, and the `body` is accessible (i.e `GetPosts['body']`). With the above, it is not easy to access and I'll probably need to create a separate re-usable type definition to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Do you have TypeScript strict mode enabled? You can do by setting the "strict" option to true in tsconfig.ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost hit the spot with your initial types. Two changes required:

1. Make `body` of `GetPosts` of type `void`
2. Make `body` of returned function required

```js
interface RequestInterface {
  endpoint: string;
  body?: unknown;
}

interface GetPosts extends RequestInterface {
  endpoint: "/posts";
  body: void;
}

interface CreatePost extends RequestInterface {
  endpoint: "/posts";
  body: string;
}

function Factory<R extends RequestInterface>(endpoint: R["endpoint"]) {
  return (body: R["body"]): void => {
    console.log(`Hitting ${endpoint} with ${body}`);
  };
}

const myLibrary = {
  getPosts: Factory<GetPosts>("/posts"),
  createPosts: Factory<CreatePost>("/posts"),
};

// @ts-expect-error
myLibrary.getPosts("something");
// @ts-expect-error
myLibrary.createPosts(999);
// @ts-expect-error
myLibrary.createPosts();

myLibrary.getPosts();
myLibrary.createPosts("Hello, StackOverflow!");
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4FcIGcwCS408SyA3gFDLIQgAmADgPahgBcy+UoA5tcgBGzegE8A-JywgA1iGYB3EJQC+lSmxKIUAcQhgACs3y5aAD0gNT6bHkLFY2igLpNW4TgHIA9CxOeBYTFOADdWelV1TUcyAGEoCDhII3xzS3prTBx8IkgYlCoaVxY2L19jMFwAmiDRTm4+SMoYaQQwYGYQZAAxRDBmKFEAHlQ010zbHIdSCAA+ZAAKYvcONABtT2W2TwBdAEpnAQSwLCguhdrOVA3a3b3Q8OQAXnmqARoETtxmABsIADofsxeAsAAYACWAYHaIF4yAAJOQtuAVMgFFCABYI8i1FSgvbqGhqNSUT4gVIAW1EABlgIIoHBBs9DjRePoUpVOL02gNhnpDBVcLMFj4-JVPHsADQCBAJJIQDm4Ll9XlDeKJZIVYWiwUS6VNbzeZAAAUqAFoIGZGBA2haoFABpQqbT6YzRP82QKTCLvhT9Bi+BLKIaTebLdbbdAHVAnTS6QzBv9ZRqFYKFgBOTMEkOm3AWq02sB26Oxl0J93J+WKhYE0vxt0e9lpvYAbjrrsTlc13s84IgPyBkuQAGUwIgZAB5EIkIEKACEEqAA)

### Explanation

`never` type tells compiler that this should never happen. So, it someone tries to use `GetPosts`, it's an error, since it should never happen. `void` (`undefined` in this case should be also fine) tells that value should not be there.

Making `body` required in returned function makes it required. But since it is `void` for `GetPosts`, you can call it like `myLibrary.getPosts(undefined)` or simply `myLibrary.getPosts()` which is equivalent